# What changes do we have when we consider time dilation of light clock?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time, time-dilation

According to the special theory of relativity, in moving body all physical processes are slower than they should be for a stationary body according to the time counts of a fixed (laboratory) frame of reference.

In the case of moving mechanical clock we have changes in rate of the clock (according to mentioned above mechanical clock ticks slowly). In other case (for other types of clocks) we have the same changes too.

But what changes do we have in the case of moving light clock if speed of light is constant?

Thanks.

Comment: None. Time dilation is difference in time measured in different frames, it does not matter what clocks are used.

Comment: @kludg I didn't mean this. I mean that in different ways of time measurement (when we use different clocks) we have changes in clock work. I want to understand how it works with light clock.

Comment: Ok. I mean that changes in clock work mean that clock ticks slowly (changes in work of mechanism of clock). What changes of light clock do we have?

Comment: In your own frame you notice no slowing down of clocks. Everything goes with usual speed for you inside your frame. Only an observer in different frame may notice that your clocks slowed down. Time is relative.

Comment: @kludg You wrote that time is relative. It's true. But if you take pair of clocks then your first clock in one frame show time which differ from your second clock in rest frame. I read about this.

Comment: @kludg I asked about changes in clock mechanism.

Comment: You seem to think that we started by deriving the behaviour of general clocks and now you want to know what a light clock will behave differently. The opposite is true. Einstein's original derivation is only that light clocks, assuming speed of light is constant, will appear to be slowed down if they are moving. The result is that all other clocks will behave the same way as a light clock. There will be no other kind of behaviour. All clocks will behave that way.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent thx. I have another questions. In mechanical clock we have spring or oscillating mechanism which can be slowed down if clock is moving, but what mechanism do we have in light clock? What will be slow down in light clock?

Comment: Why don't you actually look up any one of the 999999 treatments that reproduce Einstein's light clock time dilation derivation? You can get it in both the parallel and perpendicular variants. You will understand how the light clock works and gets the time dilation factor if you do that. The problem is more of why should a property of light clocks also apply exactly the same way to other clocks, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"But what changes do we have in the case of moving light clock if speed of light is constant?"

A light-clock consists of a rigid rod of length $l$ with facing mirrors either end and a pulsed light source at point P on one mirror. The rod is stationary in the S frame, and at right angles to the velocity (magnitude $v$) of the S' frame with respect to the S frame.

Let a light pulse be emitted (event A) from point P, traverse the rod, be reflected off the other mirror and return to its starting point (event B). In the S frame the time between these events is $\Delta t=\frac{2l}c$. In the S' frame events A and B are spatially separated by distance $v\Delta t$, so the sum of the two 'slant distances' travelled by the light is $2\sqrt{l^2+(v\Delta t')^2}$ and the time between the events is $\Delta t'=\frac{2\sqrt{l^2+(v\Delta t')^2}}c$

Eliminating $l$ we get the familiar
$$\Delta t'=\frac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$

So if 'ticks' are emitted each time the light pulse passes P, the time between ticks is greater in S (in which frame point P is at a succession of different places) than in the S frame, in which P is always in the same place. In both frames the time interval is between the same two events: light leaving P and arriving back at P.

Answer (score 3):

You have the wrong idea about time dilation. Suppose you are sitting at your desk reading this and your wristwatch ticks every second. Imagine ten spaceships passing the Earth, each going at a different speed relative to the Earth. In the frame of one of the spaceships, your watch might be ticking every 1.3 seconds, say. In another it might be ticking every 5 seconds. In another it might be ticking every hour. And so on. In other words, the time between one tick of your watch and the next can take any value greater than a second in another frame, depending on the speed of that frame relative to the Earth.

Now if the time between successive ticks of your watch has ten different values in the frames of the ten different spaceships, that cannot be the result of a mechanical change to your watch, since no mechanical change could satisfy the ten different requirements. Contrary to the common expression, moving clocks do not slow down- they continue to tick at the same rate. Time dilation arises because the interval between two events is frame-dependent, so watches in one frame will naturally measure differences in durations, not because the watches run at different speeds but because the durations themselves differ.